# Formatting html input button to fit (vertically) a table cell with a rowspan

Tags: html, css, button, input, height

I'm making a calculator layout and putting all the buttons in a table cells. Here's part of the code:

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="button" class="button" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="button" class="button" value="2"></td>
    <td><input type="button" class="button" value="3"></td>
    <td><input type="button" class="button" value="-"></td>
    <td rowspan="2">
    <input type="button" class="button" value="=" style="width:100%;height:100%;">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3">
    <input type="button" class="button" value="0" style="width:100%;"></td>
    <td><input type="button" class="button" value="+"></td>
</tr>
```

So I wan't to make the '=' button to fit (vertically) the table cell it currently sitting on and I've included the css in the  tag. But it doesn't work.

I've found someone stating that styling using CSS by setting "height:100%;" but that doesn't seem to work out for me. Interestingly enough, the "width:100%;" seems to work just fine.

Can someone help me pls.

Update: I opt to use `<a>` to act as a button instead.

```
<tr>
    <td><a class="number">1</a></td>
    <td><a class="number">2</a></td>
    <td><a class="number">3</a></td>
    <td><a class="operator">+</a></td>
    <td><a class="operator">-</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><a class="numberempty" style="border-bottom-left-radius:5px;"></a></td>
    <td><a class="number">0</a></td>
    <td><a class="numberempty"></a></td>
    <td colspan=2><a class="equals">=</a></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: just add display:block to the input, and it will fit ->http://jsfiddle.net/p55czapy/

Comment: it still doesn't work @user3760661

Comment: Can you please give me more details? what it doesn't work?

Comment: the display block bit http://jsfiddle.net/p55czapy/21/ @user3760661

Answer (score 2):

add height to  `<td rowspan="2"  height="100px">`

http://jsfiddle.net/p55czapy/24/

Comment: that alters the height of the <td> cell, not the input button @KTYP

Comment: @Arez Wong try 100px instead of 100% for td. you have to explicitly set the height to td.

Comment: I did that too. It alters the height of <td>, not the button. Even still, the button did not adapted to the changes of the <td>'s new height, 100px. @KTYP

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><input type="button" class="button" value="1"></td>
<td><input type="button" class="button" value="2"></td>
<td><input type="button" class="button" value="3"></td>
<td rowspan="2" style="height: 100%;"><input type="button" class="button" value="-" style="height:100%;"></td>
<td rowspan="2" style="height: 100%;">
<input type="button" class="button" value="=" style="height:100%;">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3">
<input type="button" class="button" value="0" style="width:100%;"></td>
<td><input type="button" class="button" value="+"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Please try this hope it will help

Comment: May you please let me know what you wnat change in the design of minus sign.

Comment: i just want to format the button in the table cell with rowspan=2 so that it will fit just fine in it (both vertically and horizontally). the other buttons of the calculator is fine. and thanks but your solution still doesn't change it.@KatochAshish

Comment: I just update the code. Please check and let me know if still not got what you want.

Comment: input
{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

Try to add this in the style tag hope you will got what you want.

Comment: your updated code looks a little weird. is it possible to stretch an input type of button, vertically? or i can do the same with div block and make it react as if it is a button? @KatochAshish